# How do I print numbers in range using a method that takes a list as a parameter in JAVA?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is week 3 - exercise 15 of Mooc Java. This is what the exercise is looking for

> "Create the method `public static void printNumbersInRange(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)` in the exercise template. The method prints the numbers in the given list whose values are in the range [lowerLimit, upperLimit]."

My code seems to be fine and it gives me the right results when I try different values. However, when I run the tests I get this error

> "Method printNumbersInRange(ArrayList, int, int) of class PrintInRange missing."

Could you guys give me some light? I have been stuck for a bit here. Follow the code below, I called the  method in the main just to test.
Thanks!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintInRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Try your method here
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(360);
        list.add(-1);
        list.add(10000);
        
        System.out.println("The numbers in the range[300, 100000]");
        numbersInRange(list, 300, 100000);
    
       }
    public static void numbersInRange(ArrayList<Integer>numbers, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){
        for (Integer value : numbers){
            if(value >= lowerLimit && value <= upperLimit){
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is your `numbersInRange` method perhaps supposed to be named `printNumbersInRange`? Maybe that's what is being checked for.

Comment: Copy and paste from your excercise instructions directly into the code helps prevent problems like this.

Comment: AWW!Too many hours in front of this computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one

```
package com.company;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintInRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Try your method here
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(360);
        list.add(-1);
        list.add(10000);

        System.out.println("The numbers in the range[300, 100000]");
        printNumbersInRange(list, 300, 100000);

    }
    public static void printNumbersInRange(ArrayList<Integer>numbers, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){
        for (Integer value : numbers){
            if(value >= lowerLimit && value <= upperLimit){
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created on 8/9/20.
 *
 * @author sergio
 * @since 8/9/20
 */
public class PrintRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(360);
        list.add(-1);
        list.add(10000);

        System.out.println("The numbers in the range[300, 100000]");
        numbersInRange(list, 300, 100000);
    }

    static void numbersInRange(List<Integer> numbers, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
        numbers.stream()
                .filter(itemNumber -> itemNumber >= lowerLimit && itemNumber <= upperLimit)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The numbers in the range[300, 100000]
360
10000

Process finished with exit code 0
```